# Сложный поиск по many_many в связанной таблице

Tags: yii

Пытаюсь разобраться с AR запросами в Yii 1.x..

Есть модель `User [id, name]`

Каждый User имеет несколько моделей `Task [id, user_id]` (через `HAS_MANY`)

При этом есть еще и модель `Project [id, name]`, которая связана с `Task` через `MANY_MANY` (таблица `tasks_projects [task_id, project_id]`).

Задача - выбрать всех `User`, которым стоят задачи на проекты `projectIds[]`.

Всю голову сломал, не могу понять, как составить корректно запрос..

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;

if (isset($_data['projectIds']) && count($_data['projectIds']) > 0) {
    $criteria->with = array('tasks', 'tasks.projects'=>array('alias'=>'projects'));
    $criteria->together = true;
    $criteria->addInCondition('projects.project_id', $_data['projectIds']);
}

User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

В итоге, получаю ошибку о неверной колонке `projects.project_id`

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Пробовали сменить `project_id` на просто `id`? В ORM отсутствует понятие "таблица связей", на уровне манипулирования объектами ее не видно.

Comment: да, пробовал, не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Должно помочь, если связи в моделях правильно прописаны

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;

if (isset($_data['projectIds']) && count($_data['projectIds']) > 0) {
    $criteria->with = array('tasks', 'tasks.projects'=>array('alias'=>'projects'));
    $criteria->together = true;
    $criteria->addInCondition('tasks.projects.project_id', $_data['projectIds']);
}

User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: Нет, так тоже пробовал, конечно - результат тот же

Comment: Дайте значения relations моделей. Попробуйте изменить значения alias.